# Как записать все данные таблицы в одну переменную?

Tags: c#, asp.net

У меня есть функция который выбирает все данные из таблицы Booк.
Как записать мне все эти данные в одну переменную. Что бы дальше мог вывести циклом определенный столбец. Например так asd["Name"] или asd["Price].

```
public ActionResult Selectsql()
    {
        List<Book> asd = new List<Book>();
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; Database = mydatabase; Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Books";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
        sqlConnection1.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ......
            ......
        }
        var asd2 = asd;
        ViewBag.asd2 = asd2;
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Можете также использовать SqlDataAdapter заместо SqlReader'a:

```
       SqlDataAdapter sqlAda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       sqlAda.Fill(dt);
       sqlConnection1.Close(); // не забывайте закрывать !!
```

А дальше из работаете с таблицей.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (reader.Read())
{
  Book book = new Book() {
    Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]),
    Price = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Price"])
  };
  asd.Add(book);
}
```